# Android and Bluetooth hang (startActivityForResult)

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to improve an actual code that make a bluetooth connection with an Android phone to an  Atmega with Arduino (An electronic micro-controller). I can receive and send data to the micro-controller but the bluetooth need to be put at ON before lunching my application or it will hang and close. I do check for a bluetooth adapter and request the user to change the bluetooth state if it's at OFF but it seem the program continue and try to make a connection before getting the result of the user selection. I would like some help to find a solution to either block my program until the user input their choice or even get a better solution.

I would like to say that I'm still new to Android programming and I did read the Android activity flowchart.

I can provide logcat, but I inspected it and it clearly state that I am trying to use bluetooth even if it's not enabled ...

Here is my code :

I want to thanks anybody that could point me on the right direction

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);                  // button LED ON
    btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);                // button LED OFF
    txtArduino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArduino);      // for display the received data from the Arduino

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
    checkBTState(); 

    h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                    sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);              // extract string
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                    txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint); 
                    Log.e(TAG, "Arduino"+sbprint);

               //Test string value     
                    if(sbprint.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                        try{

                        Float sensorReading = Float.parseFloat(sbprint);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Sensor value"+sensorReading);
                        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "No int format sorry",e);

                        }
                    }   
                    if(sbprint.matches("test")){

                        Log.e(TAG, "garbage");
                    }

                   ///////

                    btnOff.setEnabled(true);
                    btnOn.setEnabled(true); 
                }
                //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                break;
            }
        };
    };





public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    /*try {
      btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }*/

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
    try {
      btSocket.connect();
      Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      try {
        btSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have all your code in onResume.  onResume is going to get called right at startup of the activity, so it will execute almost immediately.  I don't see any code in there that should delay it at all.  If you don't want to try to connect until the user selects something, then all the connection code should be in a button's click handler or something similar.

Comment: Maybe my question was badly formulated because I DO want to quit or connect when the user selects something with the BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE intent. I don't want a specific button for the connection. I tried to use a onActivityResult but I'm probably not using it correctly because it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @GabeSechan's comment about all of your code being in `onResume()`, you are also calling the Bluetooth `connect()` in your main activity thread which according to the [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAClient) is a blocking call and "should always be performed in a thread separate from the main activity thread".

Comment: Just one clarification about thread ... if I do use another thread do I call it in the onResume() ?

Comment: I'm learning this also.  We need to read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html to learn the best way to process long running and blocking tasks in background threads.